# Two instances of same string value are not equal

Tags: javascript, typescript, jasmine

Number formatted to the string of currency style returns value not equivalent to expected.

```
const expected = `12,09 €`;
const formatted = 
    new Intl.NumberFormat(`de-De`, { style: `currency`, currency: `EUR` }).format(12.09);

expect(formatted).toEqual(expected); // Fail

expected === formatted; // false

// Logged values
console.log(`FORMATTED: type = ${typeof formatted}, value = '${actual}';`);
console.log(`EXPECTED: type = ${typeof expected}, value = '${expected}';`);
// FORMATTED: type = string, value = '12,09 €'; 
// EXPECTED: type = string, value = '12,09 €';
```

But

```
new Intl.NumberFormat(`de-De`, { style: `currency`, currency: `EUR` }).format(12.09); 
// returns "12,09 €"

`12,09 €` === `12,09 €`; // true

typeof formatted; // "string"
```

Question: why two similar strings are not equal?

Comment: try doing typeof of formatted and expected variables in first case. Probably they are different which is giving false on condition.

Comment: @KaushaShah, added logged values to the question, `typeof` returns same type (`string`) for both values.

Comment: as you are saying your self that `new Intl.NumberFormat` retruns `12.09` then how can it be eqaul to `12.09 €`

Comment: @ShadabAhmed - typo, fixed

Comment: try this 'formatted.replace(/\s+/g," ")', this fixed it for me. Hope it works for you.

Comment: @NakulGawande he should rather replace in expected string, not in a formatted string. A non breaking space is there for a reason.

Comment: @AdamWolski true that. I was just giving him hint of what is wrong and what could solve his problem. Apologies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Intl.NumberFormat` returns a string with a non-breaking space (160 char code) while your `expected` string has a normal space (32 char code).

`expected[5] === formatted[5]` // false

Take a look at this thread: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/24674

I think you can workaround this simply with `replace` function. Such as:

```js
const expected = `12,09 €`.replace(/\s/, String.fromCharCode(160));

const formatted =
  new Intl.NumberFormat(`de-De`, {
    style: `currency`,
    currency: `EUR`
  }).format(12.09);


console.log(expected === formatted);
```

(Hint: it would be a good idea to extract this to a separate function that takes a string a normalize spaces)

Comment: Another idea, rather than replace just change the string to -> ``12,09\xa0€``

Answer (score 4):

Space character in `formatted` is `0xC2A0` and in `expected` it's `0x20`

Answer (score 1):

Because If you check the escaped string expected is having `%20` which is space and formatted is having $A0 which is blank.

You can check the encoding [from here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_url_encoding.htm) :

```js
const expected = `12,09 €`;
const formatted =
  new Intl.NumberFormat(`de-De`, {
    style: `currency`,
    currency: `EUR`
  }).format(12.09);

console.log(escape(expected))
console.log(escape(formatted))
```